# Ist eine Übersetzung des "To Serve Man" Wortspieles möglich?

Tags: english-to-german, wordplay

Das Thema kam vor kurzem bei einem Deutschlandbesuch auf, und trotz einiger Überlegung und Googeln, kam keine funktionierende Version heraus.

Der Bezug ist zu einer [berühmten Episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Serve_Man_%28The_Twilight_Zone%29) der klassischen US Serie *Twilight Zone*.

Kurz gesagt, ist das Wortspiel die Doppelbedeutung im Englischen, wobei *to serve man* sowohl *dem Menschen/den Menschen dienen*, als auch *den Menschen servieren [als Kochgericht]* heißen kann. Daher auch die Catchphrase *it's a cookbook*, als es um das von außerirdischen Besuchern übergebene, angebliche Buch der Weisheiten geht.

<s>Wurde diese Serie jemals in Deutschland gezeigt, und wie hieß dann diese Episode? Es gibt auf Wikipedia keine deutsche Version, weder zur Episode, noch zur Serie selber.</s>

Wie @Stephie bemerkte, listet das deutsche Wikipedia die Serie und alle Episoden. Diese Episode, Nummer 89, hatte im deutschen den Titel *Das Buch der Kanamiter*. Die Kanamiter sind hierbei die Rasse/Spezies der Außerirdischen.

Wenn nicht, gibt es einen deutschen Ausdruck, der wenigstens einigermassen das Wortspiel übersetzt? Das einzige, was mir in Sinn kam war so etwas wie *den Menschen bedienen*, aber das funktioniert wirklich hinten und vorne nicht so richtig.

Comment: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_Zone und https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_Zone/Episodenliste. Deutscher Titel: "Das Buch der Kanamiter".

Comment: Hmm, komisch, auf [Englischer Wiki Seite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Zone_%281959_TV_series%29) ist links keine "deutsch" Spalte unter Languages. Besten Dank für die links! _Das Buch der Kanamiter_?! Da hat sich offensichtlich jemand keinerlei Mühe gegeben.

Comment: nicht unbedingt - gerade Filmtitel und ähnliches werden (leider) oft nicht "übersetzt", sondern bekommen von den Produktionsfirmen "neue" Titel. Eins der klassischen Beispiele: "The Good the Bad and the Ugly" -> "Zwei glorreiche Halunken". Inzwischen auch sehr beliebt: Das Muster "Orginaltitel plus Zusatz auf Deutsch".

Comment: @Stephie "Klassisch" - ja sicher. Besonders dämlich übersetzt - ja auch. Der Mensch, der "The Good, the bad and the Ugly" zu "zwei glorreiche Halunken" gemacht hat, gehört heute noch dafür verhauen...

Comment: Mir fällt dazu der (M&M?) Werbespot ein: "Schau mal, wir sind auf der Gästeliste" - "Das ist die Speisekarte".

Comment: Wir brauchen den ganzen Satz, um eine Übersetzung zu finden. Die naivste Form "Menschen servieren" scheint zu passen, aber "einen Menschen servieren" ist nicht "einem Menschen servieren".

Comment: @userunknown Ich glaube, du hast das was nicht verstanden: dies *ist* "der ganze Satz". Es ist der Titel der Episode und bezieht sich auf den Titel des fiktiven (sprich: von den Außerirdischen) übergebenen Buches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ein

> Menschenkochbuch

könnte genauso gut "Kochen *für*" als auch "Kochen *mit*" bedeuten - Nur wird im Film glaube ich niemand gekocht?

Ein anderes Wortspiel ist

> Gutes, was man Menschen tun kann

Das würde ausnutzen, dass nicht ausgesagt wird, *für wen* das Gute gut ist, und "tun" hier sowohl "jemandem etwas (an)tun" als auch "für jemand etwas tun" heißen kann.

Comment: Ich glaube, dass kommt der Sache schon ziemlich nah: auch im Englischen ist der erste Eindruck ja, dass man dem Menschen dient, also positiv. Erst als hinterlistige Zweitbedeutung wird einem klar, dass es auch ganz, ganz anders verstanden werden kann. Das spiegelt sich bei deinem deutschen Titel auch ziemlich gut wieder. Vielleicht gibt es keine "perfekte" Version.

Answer (score 5):

> Sie lieben Menschen.

— und ich liebe Linsen mit Spätzle.

Comment: Ich hab ja besondern Kinder zum Fressen gern ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ein weiterer doppeldeutiger Name für ein solches Kochbuch:

> Für jeden Menschen das perfekte Rezept

Comment: Das ist immerhin der beste Vorschlag in diesem (älteren) Thread, ansonsten aber gilt eher das, was Beta in seiner Antwort geschrieben hat: *Doppeldeutungen und Wortwitze können selten gut übersetzt werden, und alle Versuche wirken mehr oder weniger gekünstelt.* (nur um sich dann selbst nicht dran zu halten...)  Aber letztendlich ist das "to serve men"-Wortspiel nicht wirklich übersetzbar, genauso wenig wie Hannibal Lecters letzter Satz aus dem Schweigen der Lämmer "I'm having an old friend for dinner"

Answer (score 1):

Eine Übersetzung klappt nur ohne Verb. Inspiriert von echten Titeln:

> So wird Mensch perfekt
>
> Mensch – 100 Ideen die leicht gelingen

Durch das Weglassen des Artikels bei Mensch kann die Doppeldeutigkeit erhöht werden, denn so wird impliziert, dass Mensch nur eine Sorte bzw. eine Mengenbezeichnung ist.

Allerdings ist das natürlich wesentlich augenscheinlicher als beim Originaltitel.

Answer (score -1):

Doppeldeutungen und Wortwitze können selten gut übersetzt werden, und alle Versuche wirken mehr oder weniger gekünstelt. Hier ist aber mein Versuch:

Man könnte die Tatsache ausnützen, dass Mensch in Dativ und Akkusativ Plural ohne Artikel gleich aussehen. Hier ist ein Satz, mit dem man vielleicht anfangen könnte:

> Wir sind hier, um Menschen Gut(es) bereiten/anbieten/bieten zu können..

Comment: Hmm, muss ich mir ein paar Mal über die Zunge gleiten lassen... _alles gute, dass wir Menschen bereiten_ ... oder _das_ anstatt _alles_?

Comment: Wie gesagt, gekünstelt wird es, ein Muttersprachler könnte den Satz sicher weiterentwickeln. Ich habe gerade den Satz etwas verändert (verbessert???)

Comment: Ich glaube vorher war es besser. Jetzt wird's zu lang.